# Understanding NOT EXISTS in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

I am a beginner in SQL. I am now studying EXISTS and NOT EXISTS.

**Question:**

> Retrieve the names of each employee who works on ALL projects
>   controlled by department 5.

**Answer:**

```
select fname, lname
from employee
where not exists ( (select pnumber from project where dnum = 5)
                   MINUS 
                   (select pno from works_on where essn = ssn)
                 );
```

The first select in subquery gives `(1,2,3)` and the second select gives me `(1,2,3,10,20,30)`. So `(1,2,3) - (1,2,3,10,20,30) = 0`. How does this solve the query? I am not sure if my logic is correct or the way I approach the problem.

Can someone please help me understand the solution step by step and visually if possible? thanks

[Link to the course](https://www.mscs.mu.edu/~praveen/Teaching/Fa06/Db/Lectures/ch8-queries.sql)

Comment: Exists - The select query return a result. Not exists - it didn't.

Comment: Can u use joins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the original problem was to:

> Retrieve the names of each employee who works on ALL the projects controlled by department 5.

The provided answer makes use of the equivalence of:

1. All x such that f(x)
2. No x such that not f(x)

To put that in English, the problem is equivalent to finding those employees for whom there is no project controlled by department 5 that the employee doesn't work on.

So, first find all the projects controlled by department 5, then remove from that any project that the employee works on. That's exactly what the provided answer is doing. If there is nothing left, then there is no project controlled by department 5 that the employee doesn't work on. So by the equivalance, the employee works on all the projects controlled by that department.

While this is technically correct, it can feel a little odd. Especially if it were the case that department 5 controls zero projects. If that were true, the query would return all the employees ... which might not be quite what was expected.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I have one more question. It seems like the two SELECT in subqueries are not ignored this time. Why not? because I know that MySQL ignores SELECT in a subquery. Here's the link: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html

Comment: Ah, no. I think you've misunderstood. When you use `EXISTS` it doesn't matter what is in the rows returned by the subqueries. What matters is whether anything is returned at all. If the subqueries returned records, then what was in them wouldn't matter and the content as such would be ignored. The `EXISTS` only cares that there is (or is not) something there, not what that something is.

Comment: To expand a little on that ... within the subqueries themselves (and for the purposes of the `MINUS` (or `EXCEPT` for sql-server), the content of those `SELECT`s most definitely does matter, but once the `MINUS` has been processed, the actual content of what is left (if anything) can be ignored ... it will only matter that there are or aren't some rows left.

Comment: "What matters is whether anything is returned at all". I get it clearly now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `MINUS` is an Oracle term.  SQL-Server uses `EXCEPT`.  Please read https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/07/sql-server-except-clause-in-sql-server-is-similar-to-minus-clause-in-oracle/ for more information.

Secondly, `EXISTS` returns either a `TRUE` or a `FALSE` result based on whether or not the parameter statement returns any records.  For example, `EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE Fname = 'John' )` will return `TRUE` whereas `EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE Fname = 'Slartibartfast' )` will return `FALSE`.

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_exists.asp gives a good explanation of `EXISTS` (with examples).

The `EXISTS` subquery does not need to refer to the main statement - it just needs to return at least one record in the same circumstances as when you want `EXISTS` to return `TRUE`.  For instance...

```
SELECT *
FROM Employee
WHERE Dno = 5
  AND EXISTS ( SELECT Sex
               FROM employee
               WHERE Sex = 'M'
                 AND Dno = 5 )
```

This query will return all records from `Employee` (irrespective of their `Sex`) for `Dno` `5` if that `Department` has at least one person with `Sex = 'M'`.

As for `NOT EXISTS`...

```
SELECT *
FROM Employee
WHERE Dno = 5
  AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT Sex
                   FROM employee
                   WHERE Sex = 'M'
                     AND Dno = 5 )
```

This query will return all records from `Employee` (irrespective of their `Sex`) for `Dno` `5` if that `Department` has *no* person with `Sex = 'M'`.

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.

Comment: The question is not about finding a better way to do this but to understand how EXISTS works.